# Install latest cairo lib in Ubuntu for weasyprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, cairo, weasyprint

I just installed an Ubuntu bionic instance. It comes with cairo 1.14.6 preinstalled. I need at least cairo 1.15.4 for weasyprint to work properly. Unfortunately, even after installing the latest cairo, python still picks up the old library. I would appreciate any clues.

```sh
# Install weasyprint dependencies
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info

# Check cairo lib version, prints "1.15.10-2ubuntu0.1"
dpkg -l '*cairo*'

# Install weasyprint
pip3 install weasyprint

# Test cairo version catch by python, still prints "1.14.6"
python3 -c "import cairocffi; print(cairocffi.cairo_version_string())"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @TitoLeiva check my answer and tell me if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Bionic ships with Cairo 1.15 so I'm not sure how you got Cairo 1.14.

Python will sometimes keep an internal copy of libraries. The easiest first check is

```
find /usr/local/lib/python3*/dist-packages/PIL/ -iname '*.so*' | grep cairo
```

I expect you'll find another `libcairo` there, but if not, here's how you can track down what library `cairocffi` is finding.

## Step 1: find the library that `cairocffi` is using

#### 1.0 (Background)

`cairocffi` [uses](https://github.com/Kozea/cairocffi/blob/master/cairocffi/__init__.py#L30)  `ctypes.util.find_library` to try to locate `libcairo`. 
`ctypes.util.find_library` [searches using these commands](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/util.py#L311-L312), in order, to try to locate libraries. I've converted the python code into shell script, and listed each one with a link to the original source.

#### 1.1 - Find the alternate library

Run these each of these commands until you find the library. This emulates the `find_library` search.

1) `find_library` [method 1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/util.py#L276-L281)

```
ldconfig -p | grep -Eo '\s+(libcairo\.\S+)\s+\(libc6,x86-64'
```

2) `find_library` [method 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/util.py#L112-L133)

```
gcc -Wl,-t -o /tmp/bla -lcairo 2> /dev/null | grep -E '([^\(\)]|\S)*libcairo\.([^\(\)]|\S)*'
```

3) `find_library` [method 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/util.py#L290-L295)

```
libs=$(for d in `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'`; do printf -- "-L$d "; done); ld -t $libs -o /dev/null -lcairo 2> /dev/null | grep -Eo '([^\(\)]|\S)*libcairo\.([^\(\)]|\S)*'
```

#### 1.2 Verify the library version

Once you find the library, check its version.

```
strings /some/weird/place/libcairo.so.2 | grep -E '^P\?' | grep -Eo '[0-9.]+'
```

If it matches the bad version, continue. If it doesn't, keep seaching using 1.1. Alternatively, you can also try a generic search for all Cairo libs:

```
find /usr -iname '*cairo*.so*'
```

### Step 2: Update the library

#### 2.1 Determine who owns the library

The alternate library may have been installed using `apt` or `pip`. We'll check both. 
1) Check `apt`

```
dpkg -S /some/weird/place/libcairo.so.2
```

2) Check `pip`:

```
pip list | tail -n +3 | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs pip show -f | grep /some/weird/place/libcairo.so.2
```

#### 2.2 Update the library

If you can determine which package owns the old version, upgrade that package. If not, either delete it or manually upgrade it (copy the newer `libcairo.so` over it). This should solve your problem.

Comment: this just update the cairocffi library but didn't allow to upgrade the cairo version from 1.14.6

Comment: @TitoLeiva my bad. I've rewritten the answer from scratch. Let me know if this helps you

Comment: @TitoLeiva have you tried the solution in the new answer?

Comment: yes. But it's not a solution at all. It's more a diagnostic, because this "copy the newer libcairo.so" is not so clear, starting from where do I get the libcairo.so? Also, there are more related packages to this libcairo, so I'm not sure is just copy and replace. I appreaciate your effort in the answer, but I still have the older version. I actually sent a mail to the creators, but I haven't got an answer yet.

Comment: @TitoLeiva if the correct version of libcairo2 was installed using apt, it should be in the folder `/usr/lib`. I encourage you ***not*** to overwrite the old version, but to determine what package owns it and remove or upgrade that package. The procedure listed above should guide you through that process.